# Update a key value in place in a jsonb column?

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

Let's say we have a table -

```
create table test_table(id text not null, data jsonb not null)
```

And we have values as -

```
insert into test_table values('data1', '{"name": "Rahul Jain", "emp_id": "73347", "attributes": [{"key": "name", "value": "Amay Adams", "display_name": "Name"}, {"key": "designation", "value": "Senior Software Engineer", "display_name":"Designation"}, {"key": "location", "value": "New Delhi", "display_name": "Location"}, {"key": "dept", "value": "Engineering", "display_name": "Department"}, {"key": "dept", "value": "Engineering", "display_name": "Department"}]}')
```

Now this table has millions of records. I have to update the value for the key `dept` i.e. from `Engineering` to `Technology`. I do not want to use a python script for this which fetches the values and then checks for the key and then updates. How do I do an in place update for it, updating through some query? The updates for the outer keys seem plausible but for the `attributes` array, I cannot find any way for it.

Comment: Postgres 9.5 has a function for that: `jsonb_set()` and you can use the `-` operator to remove keys: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE

Comment: we have 9.4 server on our production. cannot use this feature, I guess.

Comment: If that is important for you, then you should consider upgrading.

Comment: You cannot do that with a simple call of `jsonb_set()` either (unless the `dept` key is always at the same index within the `attributes` array). Do you want to do this regularly, or you just need a maintenance script, which will *upgrade* your data only once?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I believe you can do this using plpgsql, but it can be tricky:

```
=# select jsonb_pretty(data) from test_table;
                   jsonb_pretty                   
--------------------------------------------------
 {                                               +
     "name": "Rahul Jain",                       +
     "emp_id": "73347",                          +
     "attributes": [                             +
         {                                       +
             "key": "name",                      +
             "value": "Amay Adams",              +
             "display_name": "Name"              +
         },                                      +
         {                                       +
             "key": "designation",               +
             "value": "Senior Software Engineer",+
             "display_name": "Designation"       +
         },                                      +
         {                                       +
             "key": "location",                  +
             "value": "New Delhi",               +
             "display_name": "Location"          +
         },                                      +
         {                                       +
             "key": "dept",                      +
             "value": "Engineering",             +
             "display_name": "Department"        +
         },                                      +
         {                                       +
             "key": "dept",                      +
             "value": "Engineering",             +
             "values": "Engineering",            +
             "display_name": "Department"        +
         }                                       +
     ]                                           +
 }
(1 row)
```

Now perform an update:

```
DO
$BODY$
DECLARE
    record jsonb;
    ind int;
    path text[];
BEGIN
    FOR record IN SELECT data FROM test_table
    LOOP
        FOR ind in 0..(jsonb_array_length(record->'attributes'))
        LOOP
            IF record->'attributes'->ind->>'key' = 'dept'
            THEN
                path = ARRAY['attributes', ind::text, 'value'];
                UPDATE test_table
                    SET data = jsonb_set(data, path, '"Technology"')
                    WHERE data->>'emp_id' = record->>'emp_id';
            END IF;
        END LOOP;
    END LOOP;
END;
$BODY$ language plpgsql;
```

And here is the result:

```
=# select jsonb_pretty(data) from test_table;                                                                                                                    
                   jsonb_pretty                   
--------------------------------------------------
 {                                               +
     "name": "Rahul Jain",                       +
     "emp_id": "73347",                          +
     "attributes": [                             +
         {                                       +
             "key": "name",                      +
             "value": "Amay Adams",              +
             "display_name": "Name"              +
         },                                      +
         {                                       +
             "key": "designation",               +
             "value": "Senior Software Engineer",+
             "display_name": "Designation"       +
         },                                      +
         {                                       +
             "key": "location",                  +
             "value": "New Delhi",               +
             "display_name": "Location"          +
         },                                      +
         {                                       +
             "key": "dept",                      +
             "value": "Technology",              +
             "display_name": "Department"        +
         },                                      +
         {                                       +
             "key": "dept",                      +
             "value": "Technology",              +
             "values": "Engineering",            +
             "display_name": "Department"        +
         }                                       +
     ]                                           +
 }
(1 row)
```

Unfortunately, I'm not aware about performance of this solution.